# Como tipar respuesta route.queryParams

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy intentando tipar los datos de la respuesta de la suscripción a los parámetros de la ruta (esto es por la autenticación oauth de Strava)

Si en el siguiente código meto un console.log, la respuesta es correcta.

```
this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.interaction.setToken(params.code)
        this.interaction.setScope(params.scope)

        stop()
      }
    );
```

Pero mi intención es tener datos tipados en toda la aplicación, por eso me gustaría tener algo así

```
this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe((params: Authorization ) => {
        this.interaction.setToken(params.code)
        this.interaction.setScope(params.scope)

        stop()
      }
    );
```

Pero al tener ahí la interface Authorization me lanza un error

`error TS2769: No overload matches this call.`

Llevo un rato dandole vueltas y no entiendo que tengo mal, si en la interfaz o en donde... pero no he llegado a una conclusión.

Por cierto, la interfaz es la siguiente.

```
export interface Authorization {
    state: string;
    code:  string;
    scope: string;
}
```

Comment: Por lo que entiendo el error está en las firmas del método `.subscribe()` ya que al tipar el objeto params estás utilizando  una firma del tipo `.subscribe(obj: Authorization)` que puede no existir dentro de las definiciones del método. Lo que se me ocurre es que la primera instrucción que hagas dentro de la función sea una asignación de ese valor a una variable del tipo `Authorization` utilizando una aserción de tipo. Algo como `let auth: Authorization = params;`.

Comment: Como dice @ricardo-dlc `ActivatedRoute.queryParams()` devuelve un observable de tipo Params. `Observable<Params>` https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#queryParams y no un `Observable< Authorization >`

Comment: Gracias a ambos, como comenta @ricardo-dlc he añadido esa igualación con el params y listo, a funcionar.

Comment: Genial @Diego, considera publicar tu solución como una respuesta para que puedas ayudar a otros futuros usuarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi solución definitiva fue la siguiente.

Le mando los parámetros `Params` a una función propia `getQueryParams`

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe((p) => {
            this.params = this.oauthService.getQueryParams(p);
        });
```

En la que instancia una nueva clase y devuelvo el tipo que necesito para manejarlos por la aplicación

```
getQueryParams(params: Params): QueryParams {
        return new QueryParams(params.state, params.code, params.scope);
    }
```